# java pattern find html tag between text

Tags: java, regex

I want find text 'ABCD' in

```
String text = "<div class=\"aaaa\">1234</div>"
            + "   <li class=\"pcs05\">ABCD</li>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<li class=[^A-Za-z0-9]>(\\S+)</li>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: proper regexp will be `<li class="[A-Za-z0-9]+">(\S+)<\/li>`

Comment: Mandatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766. Any reason you can't use proper tool (HTML or XML parser like jsoup) for that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String text =  "<div class=\"aaaa\">1234</div>";
               text +=    "<li class=\"pcs05\">ABCD</li>";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<li class=\"[A-Za-z0-9]+\">(\\S+)</li>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferred tool for this kind of task is HTML or XML parser (more info [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/1393766)). One of simpler parser I like to use is [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). Nice thing about it is that it supports CSS query syntax.

So your code could look like:

```
String text = "<div class=\"aaaa\">1234</div>"
            + "   <li class=\"pcs05\">ABCD</li>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text);
String liValue = doc.select("li").text();

System.out.println(liValue);
```

Output: ABCD